# QGIS 3.28.3 Custom Print layout: Problems with changing rectangle sizes

Tags: qgis, print-composer, dynamic-text, rectangle

I'm part of a GeoOffice and we want to create a custom print layout for the finished maps. This custom print layout should include a "stamp" in the lower right corner with all the needed information: Logo of the company, date, project number, project scale, short description of the project and the map legend. For a clean appearance, we thought about creating white rectangles as a background for each line and adding a text field on top of it. I then put each rectangle together with its corresponding text field into a separate group for easy moveability across the map. But everytime I want to change the width of the lowest rectangles because of an extended legend, the overall size of the rectangle changes. And if I want to undo my changes, the rectangles keep getting smaller and smaller. Is there a way to prohibit the rectangles to change in size?
[image]

Comment: If you are ok to use HTML/CSS then the HTML Frame Item may be a solution. https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_html_frame.html?highlight=html#the-html-frame-item

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling separate items and trying to keep them in sync, you can just use the `background` setting of the text field. Then as you change it's size or position it will automatically be filled with a white (or other color) background.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But there is still a problem with moving elements in groups. I created text fields and enabled frames for each one. For a clean apperance I overlapped the frames of different text fields slightliy because you can´t customize which part of the frame should appear. Now I put the text fields into a group to move the whole thing as one. But there is still the problem that while moving the emelents the size of the frames change and empty spaces appear between the frames.